# Seeking Java EE books recommendation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm thinking of a serious training in Java EE and found there are too many books to choose from.  Could you kindly share your insights as a practicing professional in this respect?

For example, some people in other post recommend "SCWCD Exam Study Kit Second Edition
Java Web Component Developer Certification Hanumant Deshmukh, Jignesh Malavia, and Matthew Scarpino"

By quickly looking at Amazon, I found Enterprise JavaBeans 3.0 (5th Edition) [Paperback]
Richard Monson-Haefel received 141 reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the certification book.  EJB 3.0 has longevity in its favor - 5th edition tells you something.  Go with that.

You should also know that "J2EE" is 1998 vintage and out of date.  The correct name is "Java EE" for "Java Enterprise Edition".

While I'm recommending things, I'd advise you to take a look at [Spring](http://www.springframework.org).  I greatly prefer it to EJBs, even though EJB 3.1 is a big improvement over past versions of the spec.